# ROS multi-machine communication failure: invalid master URI

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, multi-machine

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have set up ROS to communicate between my robot (using raspberry pi) and my laptop. **It worked for a period of time** but  somehow stopped working suddenly. The reported error is:

```
invalid master URI:192.168.43.244:11311
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Please note that the procedures I took for ROS master and slave to communicate should have been correct or I wouldn' t have succeeded in the first few times.

I can not find any related information for this problem, so someone who has an idea please tell me what is going wrong and how I can fix this please. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293695/ros-multi-machine-communication-failure:-invalid-master-uri/) by [Seagull](https://answers.ros.org/users/33506/seagull/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> invalid master URI:192.168.43.244:11311
> ```

If this is a copy-paste, then it's indeed an invalid URI, as it doesn't include the protocol part. It should probably be:

```
http://192.168.43.244:11311
```

> **It worked for a period of time** but  somehow stopped working suddenly.

That would seem rather strange: unless you have someone else editing your files, the `http://` part would have to have dropped of on its own.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Seagull](https://answers.ros.org/users/33506/seagull/) on 2018-06-10**:
This solves the problem. My fault. I forgot to add http:// in the latter times.

**Comment by [SHIVAM](https://answers.ros.org/users/105343/shivam/) on 2022-05-19**:
Where we need to add "http://". It is there  in the bashrc file so where should I add this. Kindly help me.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-19**:
If it's already there, there wouldn't be anything to add.

You'll want to post a new question and precisely describe what you're trying to do, what you observe doesn't work, what the symptoms are, what you've tried to solve it, and refer to this question.

If it then turns out to be a duplicate, it can still be closed.